# WalletConnect for iOS is not connecting to Metamask

Tags: metamask, walletconnect

If you are developing a dApp with Wallet Connect and Metamask is not responding, check the bridge connection.

This bridge: `https://safe-walletconnect.gnosis.io/` might not be responding.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a new bridge:  `bridge.walletconnect.org` It helped me resolve the issue.